# Match First Column from First File to Line in Second File Then Insert Last Column of Matched Line from Second File as New First Column in First File

Tags: awk, command-line

I have the following two files:

```
file1:

1,foo,bar,etc
2,bar,etc,aaa
3,.......,abc
```

```
file2:

1,rand,xyz,lastcol1
aaa,bbb,ccc,2,ddd,lastcol2
xyz,3,lastcol3
```

For each first column in file1 (1,2,3), if it matches in a line from file2, the last column of that line should become the new first column of file1.

```
newfile:

lastcol1,1,foo,bar,etc
lastcol2,2,bar,etc,aaa
lastcol3,3,.......,abc
```

Comment: The command you say finds matching lines will only find 1 matching line between the 2 files as the only $1 in common between the 2 files is `1` but your sample input/output shows that ALL lines should match between the 2 files. Is your example wrong or is your code wrong? Please [edit] your question to fix whatever is wrong. Your existing code `'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]'` isn't how to find matching $1s across 2 files btw, this is: `'NR==FNR{c[$1];next}; $1 in c'`.

Comment: Removed incorrect section.

Comment: You removed your attempt to solve the problem yourself. Don't do that as it's a sure way to get your question downvoted and closed as this forum exists to help people with their code, not to write code for people, so a question without code is OT here. See [ask]. Put your code back and clarify your requirements for which fields should be used in the comparison between both files.

Answer (score 0):

Look this `awk` program:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
FNR == 1 {
    # because there are more than one file on input 
    nb_file++
}
nb_file == 1 {
    # first file memorization in hash table
    # the key is the first field
    hash[$1]=$0
    next
}
nb_file == 2 {
    # second file treatment
    # for all keys in hash table from first file...
    for (k in hash) {
        i = 1
        found = 0
        # for all columns in the second file line
        while (i <= NF) {
            # if field value equals to key name
            if ($i == k) {
                # print last field value, coma, and first file line is hash table
                print $NF "," hash[k]
                # stop when found
                found = 1
                break
            }
            i++
        }
        if (found == 1) {
            # stop when found
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```sh
$ awk -f trt.awk file1 file2
lastcol1,1,foo,bar,etc
lastcol2,2,bar,etc,aaa
lastcol3,3,.......,abc
```